# Preventing invalid characters from being written to an RSS Feed

Tags: rss, character-encoding, w3c-validation

I am working on blogging software.  Occasionally users manage to paste control characters into their blog posts (for example someone recently managed to paste in the vertical tab character,   ).  When we render the posts in an RSS Feed, XML parsers fail to parse the control character and declare the feed invalid.

One way to fix this would be to do a character-by-character scan of the string and remove any invalid characters.  This would mean maintaining a list of invalid characters.  Does anyone know if such a list already exists?

Or maybe someone knows of library that already handles this problem?  I am writing in C#, but I can port a library written in another language.

Or is there some solution that I am missing?

Note, this does not appear to be a unicode or an escaping problem.  The RSS feed displays brackets, Chinese characters, wingdings, smart quotes, etc. just fine.  It's just certain control characters that seem to make the feed not validate.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Looks like this page has a good solution:
http://cse-mjmcl.cse.bris.ac.uk/blog/2007/02/14/1171465494443.html

They get the list of valid characters from the XML spec, and just iterate through the string and strip out invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Argotic framework](http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic) for building the RSS feeds.  The library handles everything very nicely.